# Double-well potential and non-perturbative energy splitting

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiclassical, instantons, non-perturbative

(A reference for the topic is a QFT note (chapter 2
Instantons in Quantum Mechanics) [here](http://hep1.c.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Ekazama/QFT/instanton2.pdf) by Yoichi Kazama at University of Tokyo, see page 30)

Consider the double well potential in quantum mechanics,
$$
V = \lambda (x^2 - a^2)^2 \ , \qquad \omega^2 = 8\lambda a^2 \ .
$$
Computing the amplitude $\langle a | e^{-\Delta \tau H} |a \rangle$ in the $\Delta \tau \to \infty$ limit, one concludes an energy splitting between the two lowest energies,
$$
\Delta E = \omega \sqrt{\frac{\omega^3}{2 \pi \lambda}} \exp \bigg[  -\frac{\omega^3}{12\lambda} \bigg] \ .
$$

Usually we say the splitting is *non-perturbative*, since the coupling $\lambda$ appears in the denominator of the exponential. **However, what if we replace $\omega = \sqrt{8\lambda a^2}$?** In this case,
$$
\Delta E \sim \exp\bigg[  - \frac{4}{3}\sqrt{2} a^3 \sqrt{\lambda} \bigg] \ .
$$
**This doesn't seem very non-perturbative any more.**

Said differently, I want to know what is the invariant/coordinate-independent criteria for saying something is perturbative or non-perturbative?

Comment: The double well potential can be treated perturbatively as long as you are not deviating too much from the bottom of either well. But once you start having significant anharmonic effects your perturbative treatment will break down. A better approach is to treat the potential explicitly with something like a discrete variable representation or other numerical differential equation technique.

Comment: *non-preturbative* means that it is not derived via perturbation theory - which is actually not applicable when we deal with a finite coupling between degenerate states.

Comment: @RogerVadim Many notes explain the non-perturbativeness is by saying that the naive Taylor expansion around $x = 0$ of $e^{-1/|x|}$ converges to a zero function, which implies that the $\Delta E (\omega, \lambda)$ cannot be observed using perturbation in $\lambda$. However, $\Delta E (a, \lambda)$ seems obtainable as a perturbation series in $\lambda$. So I'd like to know what determines whether some effect can be obtained by perturbation theory or not.

Comment: @user31415926 how would you build perturbation series? What would you choose as unperturbed Hamiltonian and perturbation? To what level (of the two degenerate ones) are you calculating the correction? You might be misled by a sophisticated method, which hides some basic QM (E.g., there is a discussion in Landau and Livshitz)

Comment: @RogerVadim I imagine I can do the following. Take $x = a$ as a starting point, expand $V$ around it to 2nd order to have an harmonic oscillator $V_0$ + correction $V'$. The $H_0$ would be harmonic oscillator, so naively one can push perturbation calculation forward. But this is **not valid** since $V'(x)$ is **not small**. Then I will ask the question "is there a smarter/valid perturbation computation", and the next question, "how to prove that for certain quantity there is no clever perturbation computation at all".

Comment: @RogerVadim I guess one answer would be: there are only a few usable $H_0$, so one simply needs to try them all to declare no perturbation method is available.

Comment: In your approach you break symmetry by hand. In fact, we have an oscillator state in the left well, and an identical state in the right well. So, if you tried to look for a correction to the state in one well, you would have the first term like $V^2/(E_0-E_0)$ - the perturbative solution is not possible. Same, if you take symmetric and anti-symmetric configurations. In fact, following the standard PT, in such cases you solve *exactly*(=*non-perturbatively*) for the  first PT correction, which here means diagonalizing a 2-by-2 matrix.

Comment: then you can move to more sophisticated methods of calculating matrix element(=splitting), which is what your book is busy with.